# Input Mismatch Expection Error on coursework

Tags: java, eclipse

So I've got my first piece of `coursework` due tomorrow and I keep getting the same `error` and I can't fix it, I am not looking for someone to just give me the solution but some guidance would be much appreciated.

The code im using is :

```
double discountRate = 20;
int totalBookings = 0;

while (S.hasNext()) {
    // String seatType = S.next();
    double price = S.nextDouble();
    int bookings = S.nextInt();

    System.out.format("Seat Type  : %s, ", S.next());

    //sums 

    System.out.format("Seat Price : £%.2f, Bookings : %d", price, bookings);

    //totalBookings = totalBookings + bookings;
    totalBookings += bookings;

    System.out.format("Total Bookings : %d", totalBookings);
```

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayyzc.png)

Comment: You might want to show us what the input looks like. This would probably help answering your question. And you should rather post code than an image of code.

Comment: Share seats.txt content

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)

Comment: `while (S.hasNext()) { ... S.nextDouble();`: you need to check that `S.hasNextDouble()`.

Comment: Ok i have edited the post and included the code, thanks for the reply but could you please elaborate? Im about as beginner as it gets haha

Comment: Also the seats.txt content is:
1ST(Table)
48.50
2

1ST
44.50
3

STD(Table)
28.50
3

STD
24.50
5

Comment: You seem to be running a different version of your code than what is shown in your editor window. The stacktrace implies you've called Scanner.double at line 20, but line 20 actually calls Scanner.next. So we don't even know what code is causing this problem.

Comment: Oh really? What would you suggest i do? This coursework is just to learn the basics and such so im not too worried but just want to understand where im going wrong and learn how to code better, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message closely. The stack trace shows that the error occurred when you called `Scanner.nextDouble()`. Now look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) of that method. It says:

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw
>   InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
>   valid double value.

Look at your input. The first token is "1ST(Table)". A token containing letters is not valid for `nextDouble()`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense just unsure on what to change it to. Could you give me some examples please. Thanks for ur patience and help

Comment: It looks like it should work if you reinstate the statement `String seatType = S.next();`. Why did you comment it out? (Of course, you should also replace `S.next()` in the System.out.format statement with `seatType`.)